# Weird behaviour for a basic if in php, how i can change/solve it?

Tags: php, session

I have just encountered a very weird behaviour for an if in php. It's just few lines of basic code but don't know how to solve or bypass this problem... This is the code:

```
if($includepage!="page" && $includepage!="page_two"){

    header('Location: logout.php');

}
```

It's just an if, i use it to check if i'm trying to navigate a page different from "page" or "page_two", if yes i'll redirect user to a page that destroy session and force logout. The variable `$includepage` is correctly filled with a string value like page,page_two,page_three,page_four... so this isn't the root of the problem. I have already tried to change the operator to `!==` but it doesn't solve the problem. However the strange behaviour is that: the redirect is executed also when the $includepage=="page" or "page_two". It happens only in php version > 5.3.2 (i can test it in 5.6,5.5), in version 5.3.2 (i have test two istance, one local and one web) all works correctly...

debugging the code i have find something else very weird, if i place an echo inside the if in php version > 5.3.2 , like this:

```
if($includepage!="page" && $includepage!="page_two"){
    echo ("if i enter here i'll do logout");
    //header('Location: logout.php');

}
```

It never be printed when i navigate in page "page" or "page_two" ... with that echo all works correctly... But if i return to the original version:

```
if($includepage!="page" && $includepage!="page_two"){

         //echo ("if i enter here i'll do logout");
        header('Location: logout.php');

}
```

The header location will be executed when i navigate in "page" or "page_two". I have tried also to change the way i check the page name:

```
$ArrayPages=array("page","page_two");

if(!in_array($includepage, $ArrayPages)){

    header('Location: logout.php');
}
```

No changes. At my eyes this behaviour doesn't make sense... What i can do to investigate the reasons? How i can solve it?

this is a php_info of a working 5.3.2 version:

```
session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

This is the session section in a phpinfo of a weird working 5.6 php version:

```
session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress upload_progress
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

EDIT

ok i'm sorry, maybe i'm not clear. I can print the value of $includepage, before and inside the if. I know exactly that it contains a string. The value of the string can be "page", "page_two", "page_three"... It depends from the page i actually navigate. The problem is : when $includepage=="page" the redirect will be executed anyway, but when $includepage=="page" i expected the opposite behaviour.

Comment: Your question is unclear - I can't quite grasp what your issue actually *is*. That said, you can't `echo` before a `header` without things breaking, and you should `exit` or otherwise end the script after a `header('Location: ...')` call.

Comment: Have you tried to dump the value to check it?
`if($includepage!="page" && $includepage!="page_two") var_dump($includepage);`

Comment: Print the value of $includepage before the if statement. Further, print it with something to ensure it doesn't have whitespace, such as `echo "#$includepage#";`

Comment: i have tried to var_dump($includepage), before and inside the if, it filled correctly without spaces with a string as i want. A string like the two i already check "page" or "page_two"

Comment: i know that i can't echo before and header, when i echo it is for debug purpose and whit the header commented "//".

Comment: To make it simple: If you can't figure out how to print the value of $includepage before the if statement, you will never realize that $includepage doesn't contain what you THINK it contains and you will never realize that this isn't a problem with the if statement.

Comment: ok i'm sorry, maybe i'm not clear. I can print the value of $includepage, before and inside the if. I know exactly that it contains a string. The value of the string can be "page", "page_two", "page_three"... It depends from the page i actually navigate. The problem is : when $includepage=="page" the redirect will be executed anyway, but when $includepage=="page" i expected the opposite behaviour.

Comment: You should consider adding this information to the question so people are less likely to vote for closing it as unclear.

Comment: jus added, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Today, after a long stop and a restart of the entire system the problem seems to be disappeared, i don't know what is happened.